# Why are the nodes in red bigger and the ones in blue smaller for the same command

Tags: color, nodes, text

This is our Tex code, I don't know why the blue one below is smaller, and I want to ask, how to change the thickness of the text in the node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,fill=red!50, inner sep=0pt ] (a) at (0,0){+};
\node[circle,draw,fill=blue!50, inner sep=0pt ] (b) at (1,0){-};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `-` in text mode doesn't render "minus" but hyphenation character (divis, hyphen). And hyphen isn't visual compatible with `+` which renders like plus in both: math mode and text mode. Never print hyphen when you want to print minus. I.e. always put such `-` into math mode: `$-$`. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,fill=red!50, inner sep=0pt ] (a) at (0,0){+};
\node[circle,draw,fill=blue!50, inner sep=0pt ] (b) at (1,0){$-$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It’s called hyphen, not divis. I’d use also `$+$`, not only for the sake of symmetry.

Comment: Divis is from Latin terminology. Of course, it is hyphen in English. My English is poor, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `+` and `-` characters have different sizes. If you want the nodes to have the same size then you need to set a (big enough) minimum size. In this case `3.5mm` seems to work:

[image]

I would also recommend defining a `TikZ` style for your nodes so that you do not need to type out the specifications twice. Do this your code becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  mynode/.style = {
    circle,
    draw,
    fill=red!50,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=3.5mm,
  }
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[mynode] (a) at (0,0){+};
    \node[mynode] (b) at (1,0){-};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, what you wrote is what I need. I would like to ask an additional question. It seems that only one type of node can be defined in a \tikzset{}. When I additionally define a blue node in {}, it does not compile and work.

Comment: @ZhaoDazhuang No, you can create multiple styles in one `\tikzset`. Without knowing what you did, I can't say what went wrong, but for example `\tikzset{foo/.style={blue, circle}, bar/.style={red, draw, thick}}` would create two style, `foo` and `bar`. Note a comma between the two definitions.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you very much, it works